# Yii framework: best way to embed images in "posts"?

Tags: yii

I have a simple "post" AR class/table. Its based on the "blog tutorial" so it serves the same purpose. 
I want to be able to embed images into posts. My design was as follows and I wasn't entirely happy with it so I'll be happy for your feedback:

**Design suggestion**: Directory **protected/data/posts_files/{post_id}** would be the repository of posts "resources" (images in our case, but can be anything). Post authors need to put the used images/files in the right location (after the post is created since its id is needed). My needs are really humble so from convenience point of view this is ok. When a post that include such images is requested, CAssetManager will be called to the rescue, to "publish()" the directory of that post (e.g. protected/data/posts_files/17).
In the posts themselves (in their "content" or "body" - which ever term you prefer), images will be embedded with **img** tags that the src attribute pointing to the published directory for this post_id in the assets folder (for example, after publishing a specific post, **WEBROOT/assets/d379e294/some_image.gif**).

Problem is that when the post is created/edited, I do not know what path the CAssetManager will create and return - that seemingly random text string (**d379e294** in the example above). So, I need on runtime, when loading the 'post', to update its content live, after publishing has been made, with the correct url/paths in the 'src' attribute of the img tags (or for every other kind of resource linked in that 'post').

This was a little challenging: Initially I went with a PHP variable in the 'post' content/body and tried to somehow interpolate it when loading or just before rendering the post. I wasn't successful. I used PHP's **eval()**, which is very bad practice and dangerous by itself, and it kept crashing complaining on the other content within the 'post' body. 
I resorted to have some simple place holder string in the body of the posts - "**ASSETS_URL**" and **str_replace()** it when loading the post with the published assets path that I "now" have at hand (at runtime).

I'm not sure this is the best approach. this place holder string could be needed in some post and besides, that seems like a basic templating engine start and my intuition tells me I'm missing something if I do a simple templating engine inside a framework. I just can pin point on the 'right' alternative, the best practice alternative, to do it in Yii. 
I wanted to ask for your opinion on this - both on the design of the solution from the higher level and on the design of the implementation itself. Would you change things and make them different?

(I didn't want to dive into KcFinder so intentionally left it out).

Thanks,
Boaz.

Comment: Imho, it seems your entire problem arises because you are using CAssetManager. What advantage does it actually give you? And what exactly do you mean when you say: `Post authors need to put the used images/files in the right location (after the post is created since its id is needed).` Do post authors have access to your directories? Is this an intra company app or something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Imho, it seems your entire problem arises because you are using CAssetManager. What advantage does it actually give you?

I would suggest making a directory under your application's root, say : `root/post_files/{post_id}/` and storing the post related files there. You can store paths for related post files in the db, and retrieve the file, when needed, using that stored path.

I'm no expert, just my suggestion.

Comment: do comment on my suggestion and answer my queries to your question.

Comment: I guess there's no real justification for using CAssetManager in this case and you're pointing in the right direction. CAssetManager will be good if I need to publish some reasources that are contained in a module or some other encapsulated container, which is not our case.

Comment: yup, that's the right use of assets, AFAIK. so i was wondering, how it would help in your case. Anyway, great that you agree with me.

Answer (score 1):

Please read the class reference for Yii, it is an amazing tool and is meant to be used.

http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CAssetManager#publish-detail

If you use the hashByName optional parameter the assetManager will **always** return the same url if given a folder with the same name as the parameter. However if you try to publish multiple files/folders with the same names with this parameter then it will do nothing assuming that the file/folder already is published, as it hashes by file/folder name rather than the concatenation of parent directory name and modification time.

Then upon the edit of said post just republish with the optional forceCopy to update said files.

As to respond to other's post saying

> there's no real justification for using the CAssetManager in this
>   case

I would like to respond with the fact that obfuscating your directory layout and code is always the best option to avoid being hacked. Especially in a language like php where its limitations are so well known.

Also it allows for you to hide your "uploads" folder so because most of the time it would be with permissions 777 or 755 depending on your web host and setup. This allows you to protect yourself further.